# jQuery DataTables.js How to Apply It On Admin Grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, phtml, js-css, datatable.js

I'm very new to Magneto, I'm trying to add jQuery DataTables in `Magento 2.3`, in below image i get error in console:

**Here is my Code:**

Add file in `/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js`.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            dataTableJs: 'ES_Downloads/js/jquery.dataTables.min'
        }
    }
 };
```

includ css file like below in `/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/layout/downloads_index_reports.xml`

```
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="ES_Downloads::css/dataTables.min.css"/>
    </head>
```

I moved my css and js files into respective folders. e.g
`/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/web/js/datatables.min.js`
`/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/web/css/datatables.min.css`

I used below code in my template file to load DataTable.

```
<table>
  ....
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','dataTableJs'], function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
});
</script>
```

Seems DataTable is not loading, getting below error in console:
[image]

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i was somewhere else maybe mentally :P... Their were too many typo in my code:

In `/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js.`

```
 var config = {
    map: {
   '*': {
       dataTables: 'EC_Downloads/js/datatables.min'
     }
   }
 };
```

In `/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/layout/downloads_index_reports.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="EC_Downloads::css/datatables.min.css"/>
    </head>
```

In `/EC/Downloads/view/adminhtml/templates/test.phtml`

```
<table>
   ...
</table>

<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','dataTables'], function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
});
</script>
```

Run these command:

```
sudo rm -rf var/ pub/static/adminhtml generated/
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```